# Is there a better way to insert into a table than below?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a need where I need to use two queries which differ from each other by a single condition.
Eg.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table
 WHERE attribute1 = 'Y';

SELECT * 
  FROM table
 WHERE attribute1 IS NULL;
```

My need is to insert data from these two queries into a single table the only condition being that the data from the first query should go in first and then the second query.
I can obviously run the first query first insert and run the second query and then insert again.
My question is there a better way to do that?

Comment: What is the purpose of the first result to be inserted before the second one. It may be an XY problem, because if you *really know* that you need this (not *think* that it is required), you should most probably know how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the # of rows you are requesting is significant percentage of the table, then no, there is no better way to do that. If you require that the first insert happen before the second insert, then the way to guarantee that is to do each in order, as separate SQL statements. Any combining of the two leads to the possibility of mixing the results. Sure, you can force ordering with `ORDER BY`, you can make assumptions about `UNION ALL` (but with concurrent union PX in recent versions, this is not a safe assumption), but these are all inferior methods to simply using two statements. A sort can be quite expensive.

If however you are querying a *massive* table and each of your queries expects only a *small* percent of rows, then the cost of a sort *might* be cheaper than two table scans. In that case, you can combine the queries and force the order with an explicit `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT *
  FROM your_table
 WHERE NVL(attribute1,'Y') = 'Y'
ORDER BY DECODE(attribute1,'Y',1,2)
```

But unless this is necessary to achieve the performance goals at hand, it is less clear and therefore not a great way to code. Most likely in your situation, using two statements is best from all perspectives.

Comment: Unfortunately for my case the first query will fetch a significant amount of data and the second will be quite small. I will go to with the separate query approach for now and see the program performance. Thanks for the help @Paul W.

Comment: What's the reason for the requirement that the first one be loaded first?

Comment: I am building a custom logic for order reservation where one set of orders have to prioritized first every time and then the next set. But all the info comes from the same standard oracle tables itself for both the 'selects' .

Comment: You should avoid a design where the order of inserts is important (unless you are relying on row locking in a race condition to enforce a first-wins only rule). Relational data should normally be row-order agnostic. Instead, use column values (like maybe a date, or a priority #) at query time (not insert time) to prioritize between rows.

Answer (score 1):

To me, it looks like

```
SELECT *
  FROM your_table
 WHERE (   attribute1 = 'Y'
        OR attribute1 IS NULL);
```

---

A (worse) alternative would be to `union` (`all`) these two selects:

```
SELECT *
  FROM your_table
 WHERE attribute1 = 'Y'
UNION ALL
SELECT *
  FROM your_table
 WHERE attribute1 IS NULL;
```

Comment: OP wants to ensure that the data from the first query goes in before the data from the second query. That will probably happen under the second suggestion (UNION ALL) but due to the possibility of PQ concurrent union might not in some cases.

Comment: Aha. OK then, two separate inserts it is, looks like the simplest option.

Comment: Oracle may expand `OR` as a union query on it's own (or with `use_concat` hint). But anyway ordering on `select` has no value without direct path insert: there's no guarantee that Oracle will store them in that order. So it's not clear what OP actually wants